# MKStoreKit not storing purchased Products

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I'm using MKStoreKit to implement an IAP into my application. Everything does as expected when purchasing the product, no error messages at all. The product is purchased using the following code..

```
 [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"pro_upgrade" 
                                onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature)
 {
     NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);
     // provide your product to the user here.
     // if it's a subscription, allow user to use now.
     // remembering this purchase is taken care of by MKStoreKit.
 }
                               onCancelled:^
 {
     // User cancels the transaction, you can log this using any analytics software like Flurry.
 }];
```

After the product has been purchased I recieve the notification (via the code below) which confirms the purchase..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector (subscriptionPurchased:) 
                                             name: kSubscriptionsPurchasedNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

After the purchase I execute the following code (as documented) to determine if the product has been purchased..

```
if([MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"pro_upgrade"]) {
    NSLog(@"This feature is purchased.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"This feature is not purchased");
}
```

It constantly returns NO for the product ID. This happens when running the app in the same instance as when the product was purchased as well as closing the app and opening it. Running the app using Development or Distribution certificates make no difference at all. Further more I can't find where exactly MKStoreKit stores the product purchased BOOL that it seems to be looking for (it's pretty deep in the code so i'm not saying it does or doesn't, i just can't find it). My app is storing other information using NSUserDefaults so that isn't the issue.

Any help you can offer will be extremely appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Also worth noting it's a subscription based IAP. I also get the following error message in the console..

Review request cannot be checked now: (null)

Comment: review request cannot be checked now is fine.

Answer (score 0):

MKStoreKit doesn't store in NSUserDefaults.
I use keychain instead. Place a breakpoint in the method
storeData:forKey: (writing this method name straight from my head
without looking at code, search for similarly named methods) and try
debugging it. This is the place I save your purchases.

Do remember that purchases are remembered even after deleting and
reinstalling the app.

Comment: Your documentation however does say that you use NSUserDefaults. Perhaps you should update this. https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit#readme